# IOS translate to monotouch audio fix ios6

Tags: ios, audio, video, xamarin.ios

This code is needed for audio bug that seems to be in ios 6 update: My video plays with no audio on ios 6 devices.

Saw this code  was a fix but not sure how to translate this to monotouch:

```
NSError *error= nil;
if ([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback  
  error:&error]) {
      NSLog(@"Error setting audio session: %@", error);
}
```

Also not sure where I should even put this code? by the video player creation code or in the open of the viewcontroller the video player is created in?

Is there any way I can cause a memory leak by creating a fresh new instance on each video player creation, if so how do I properly release the resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't work previously with `AVAudioSession` but [this answer](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7778/avaudiosession-mixwithothers-property-override) migh help.

```
AVAudioSession.SetCategory(your_category, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers, out error);
```